# Implementing a minimum method in a linked list that returns a message if the queue is empty or returns the lowest value of the queue

Tags: c#

minimum method which returns a string to allow the empty message. i am having errors with not all code paths returning a value?

the idea of this method is to return the minimum value stored in a linked list. if the linked list is empty then to return the message saying the queue is empty.

side note: i am trying to implement a queue with a lined list

```
public string Minimum()
     {
        string min = "The Queue is empty";

        if (head == null)
        {
              return min;
        }

        SLLNode curr = head;
        SLLNode prev = null;

        int minimum = 0;

        while (curr != null)
        {
            // have a match 
            if (curr.NodeValue <= minimum)
            {

                minimum = curr.NodeValue;

                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.Next;

                min = minimum.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                // advanced curr and prev
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.Next;
            }

            return min;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        }
        //return min;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your function simplified. You initialised `minimum` to `0` instead of either to the first node's value, or a high value. You unnecessarily used two pointers, and duplicated the node pointer fetch inside an `else`. You tested `<=` but `<` would do.

```
public string Minimum()
    {
        string min = "The Queue is empty";
        if (head == null)
        {
           return min;
        }
        SLLNode curr = head;
        int minimum = curr.NodeValue;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            if (curr.NodeValue < minimum)
                minimum = curr.NodeValue;
            curr = curr.Next;
        }
        min = minimum.ToString();
        return min;
    }
```